# jQuery append/prepend in loop - all elements appear together when they should be displayed one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a loop in which I append/prepend a single element into a parent element. jQuery does not show any of the child elements until the loop has finished.

Take the following code as an example:

```
var i=0;
while (i < 10000) {
    $('#content').prepend($('<div>').html(++i).append($('<br>')));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/minlare/rancec7m/

Is there any way to ensure the single elements are displayed one by one?

Comment: Is this behaviour you are expecting instead: https://jsfiddle.net/rancec7m/4/  ?

Comment: Yes but without the delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, no there isn't, however it's more down to the renderer of the browser than jQuery.

Also note that it would be much quicker to create one long HTML string and use a single `append()` call to the DOM than it is to append 10,000 relatively small strings to the DOM.

```
var i = 10000, html = '';
while (i > 0) {
    html += '<div>' + i-- + '</br></div>';
}
$('#content').append(html);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rancec7m/2/)

If you definitely want the effect of each div appearing one after the other you could use a queue, however it would not be fast.

Comment: Can you explain why it is not possible? Something to do with the way the parent element is re-rendered?

Comment: It's to do with how the browser handles UI updates internally. In basic terms it debounces update requests that happen in quick succession so that the UI is only updated after the last one completes. This is because redrawing the entire UI is not a cheap process (in performance terms) and attempting to update the DOM 10,000+ times within a fraction of a second will cause issues.